# exercice for limits problems

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

We consider the problem

$$
\begin{cases}
x^2 y''+ x\, y'+\lambda\, y = 0 \\
y(1)=y(e)=0
\end{cases}
$$

The question is to find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions for this problem.

I try to put $y(x)=x^r$ and plug it in the equation, then we obtain the characteristic equation

$$
r^2 + \lambda = 0
$$

In the case $\lambda > 0$ we put $\lambda = \alpha^2$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^\star_+$. Then the characteristic equation is

$$
r^2 + \lambda = 0
$$

Case 1. If $\lambda > 0$ We put $\lambda = \alpha^2$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^\star_+$. 
Then the general solution of the equation is

$$
y(x)=C_1 \cos(\alpha\, x)+ C_2 \sin(\alpha\, x).
$$

We have $y(1)=0 => C_1=0$ and $y(e)=0 => C_2 \sin(\alpha\, e)=0$

$\sin(\alpha\, e)=0 => \alpha\, e = \pi + 2\, k\, \pi, \ k \in \mathbb{Z}^\star$

Then the eigenvalues are $\lambda= \alpha^2$ where $\alpha= \dfrac{\pi}{e}+ \dfrac{2\,k\,\pi}{e}$
My solution is correct?

Comment: I assume the differential equation is: $x^2 y'' + x\,y' + \lambda\,y=0$? And how does the characteristic equation change from $r^2+r+\lambda=0$ to $r^2+\lambda=0$? I assume you made a typo in the first?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. I edit my post

Comment: i have another solution

Comment: can you give me your solution please

Comment: You first state that the solution is of the form $y(x) = x^r$, but later use a totally different solution.

Comment: can you give me an answer please to show your solution suggest. Tkan you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initially correctly state that $y(x)=x^r$ is a potential solution. This solution can be generalized to

$$
y(x) = \sum C_i\, x^{r_i},
$$

where $r_i$ is one of the solutions to the characteristic equation $r^2+\lambda=0$. The solution to characteristic equation is $r=\pm\sqrt{-\lambda}$. So the generalized solution can be written as

$$
y(x) = C_1\, x^{\sqrt{-\lambda}} + C_2\, x^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}}.
$$

When you substitute in the two boundary conditions you get

$$
\begin{cases}
y(1) = C_1\, 1^{\sqrt{-\lambda}} + C_2\, 1^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}} = C_1 + C_2 = 0 \\
y(e) = C_1\, e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}} + C_2\, e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}} = C_1\left(\cos\sqrt{\lambda} + i\sin\sqrt{\lambda}\right) + C_2\left(\cos\sqrt{\lambda} - i\sin\sqrt{\lambda}\right) = 0
\end{cases}
$$

Solving this yields $C_1 = C_2 = 0$ or $C_2 = -C_1$ and $\sin\sqrt{\lambda} = 0$. The first solution is the trivial zero solution. The solution to the second case gives the eigenvalues $\lambda = k^2\, \pi^2\ \forall\, k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

The corresponding eigenfunctions for these eigenvalues are

$$
\begin{align}
y_k(x) & = C \left(x^{i\, k\, \pi} - x^{-i\, k\, \pi}\right) \\
& = C \left(e^{i\, k\, \pi \log x} - e^{-i\, k\, \pi \log x}\right) \\
& = 2\,i\,C \sin\left(k\, \pi \log x\right) \\
& = C' \sin\left(k\, \pi \log x\right)
\end{align}
$$

where $C'$ is just some constant.

Comment: this is the case $\lambda <0$. In the case $\lambda >0$ who's the eigenfunctions? please

Comment: @jiji added the simplified expression for eigenfunctions. I am no sure what you mean by the rest of your comment.

Comment: $y_k(x)$ is defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ or for just $x >0$? Beacause i found one solutioon when the author put $x=e^t$ and found the eignenvalues $\lambda >0$ and eigenfunctions defined for $x >0$

Comment: @jiji It depends on when you find something "defined", if you want it to be real, then no that eigenfunction is not well defined for $x<0$ (in either case the function is also not well defined at $x=0$). Are you sure that the author found that solution to the same kind of differential equation?